# How do you find the partial derivative of $F(u, v) = f(x(u, v), y(u, v))$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Suppose that $F(u, v) = f(x(u, v), y(u, v))$, where $f$ is a function satisfying $f(1, 2) = 3$,
$f_x(1, 2) = 1$ and $f_y(1, 2) = −2$. Suppose further that $x(u, v) = u + v − 1$ and $y(u, v) = 3uv − 1$. Find $F_u(1, 1)$. (Note: likely this is a typo.)

Can someone please explain how to solve this because I really don't know how?

The answer is supposedly    $-5$.

Comment: You can't. You could possibly find $F_u(1,2)$, but you don't have enough information for $x=1, y=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $F(u, v) = f(x(u, v), y(u, v))$, we want to first find $F_u(u, v)$ in order to evaluate it. We know that $f$ depends on both $x,y$ and each of those depend on $u$.

$$F_u(u, v) = f_u(x(u, v), y(u, v)) = f_x(x,y) x_u(u,v) + f_y(x,y) y_u(u,v)$$

Or with less notation,

$$F_u = f_u = f_x x_u + f_y y_u$$

This should give you a start, though as Thomas said in the comments, you can't hope to find $F_u(1,1)$! $F_u(1,2)$ on the other hand does indeed equal -5.

Comment: Thanks! This question is from my exam review I guess it was just a mistake then.